# Manually Add Items to ComboBox

Tags: combobox, devexpress

I've been looking at devexpress documentation on how to manually add a list of items to a combo box.

Can anybody help me with this please.

```
dx:ASPxComboBox ID="ddl_time" runat="server" ValueType="System.String">
     <Columns>
      <dx:ListBoxColumn Caption="First Name" FieldName="FirstName" Name="firstname"/>  
    </Columns>
</dx:ASPxComboBox>
```

this is all I can find.
I don't want to do it from a datasource just add the items manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Option 1

If you use the code below, in your code behind, you can see the result.

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddl_time.DataSource = GetDataSource();
    ddl_time.DataBind();
}

private DataTable GetDataSource()
{
    //datatable definiton
    var dtSource = new DataTable();
    dtSource.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    dtSource.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
    //fill sample rows
    dtSource.Rows.Add(1, "Item One");
    dtSource.Rows.Add(2, "Item Two");
    dtSource.Rows.Add(3, "Item Three");
    dtSource.Rows.Add(435438792, "Item Drink");

    return dtSource;
}
```

### Option 2

If you use this way you should remove the `Columns` tag definition.

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = new ListEditItem("Item One", 1);
    ddl_time.Items.Add(item);
    item = new ListEditItem("Item Two", 2);
    ddl_time.Items.Add(item);
    item = new ListEditItem("Item Three", 3);
    ddl_time.Items.Add(item);
    item = new ListEditItem("Item Drink", 435438792);
    ddl_time.Items.Add(item);
    ddl_time.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

### Option 3

```
<dx:ASPxComboBox ID="ddl_time" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0">
    <Items>
        <dx:ListEditItem Selected="True" Text="Item One" Value="1"></dx:ListEditItem>
        <dx:ListEditItem Text="Item Two" Value="2"></dx:ListEditItem>
        <dx:ListEditItem Text="Item Three" Value="3"></dx:ListEditItem>
        <dx:ListEditItem Text="Item Drink" Value="435438792"></dx:ListEditItem>
    </Items>
</dx:ASPxComboBox>
```

To add items in editor:
[image: Add Items]